# how can i add a delete link/button option in a drupal 6 module?

Tags: php

```
$block_content = l('delete', 'onthisdate/'.$links->cid);
```

I have used this `l()` function to create a delete link but after clicking this delete link how can i delete a data from my database. I want to delete data for `$cid` that means if `$cid=1` then row 1 will be deleted. I will wait for your easiest answer please.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a [hook_menu](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_menu/6) implementation in your module that maps the 'onthisdate/%cid' URL to a function to handle the database deletion, similar to the example below from the [User Badges module](https://drupal.org/project/user_badges):

```
$items['admin/user/user_badges/delete/%'] = array(
  'title' => 'Delete badge',
  'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
  'page arguments' => array('user_badges_delete_form', 4),
  'access arguments' => $access,
  'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  'file' => 'user_badges.admin.inc',
);
```